# Helm: grabbing content of a file from values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to put the content of a configuration file inside `values.yaml` and get it.

For example:

This is the values.yaml:

```
configuration: |
  [core]
  # Some comments
  my_folder = /usr/local/my_folder

  # The folder where my app should store its log files
  # This path must be absolute
  base_log_folder = /usr/local/app/logs

  # Logging options
  remote_logging = False
  remote_log_conn_id =
  remote_base_log_folder =
  encrypt_logs = False
```

and this is a configMap where I should put the content in:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "{{ template "app.fullname" . }}-config"
data:
  my.cfg: |
{{ HELM }}
```

In "HELM" tag, I tried several options of `tpl` and `include`, all without reaching my goal.

As non-optimal solution I put the content of my `configuration` in a file and grab it with

```
{{ .Files.Get "files/my.configuration" | indent 4 }}
```

I am asking for some suggestions about the possibility to have all in `values.yaml`, please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `|` on your YAML, you are defining a [Multiline YAML String](https://yaml-multiline.info/), which means that your `configuration` key has a single string value with line breaks on it (`\n`).

You can simply define your ConfigMap template like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "{{ template "app.fullname" . }}-config"
data:
  my.cfg:
{{- toYaml $.Values.configuration | nindent 4 }}
```

After rendering, the resulting ConfigMap will be deployed as:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  my.cfg: |
    [core]
    # Some comments
    my_folder = /usr/local/my_folder

    # The folder where my app should store its log files
    # This path must be absolute
    base_log_folder = /usr/local/app/logs

    # Logging options
    remote_logging = False
    remote_log_conn_id =
    remote_base_log_folder =
    encrypt_logs = False
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
```